# While creating a table in MySql database, NullPointerException encountered

Tags: java, mysql

With Netbeans 8.2, It runs perfectly.

But in Eclipse Neon 3, after adding mysql connector jar, still the problem persists

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Table {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
            Properties p = new Properties();
            p.load(f);
            String qry = "Create table Table1(values integer(2) primary key)";
            String driver_name = p.getProperty("Driver");
            String url = p.getProperty("url");
            Class.forName(driver_name);
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, p);
            Statement s = c.createStatement();
            s.execute(qry);
            System.out.println("Table created successfully!");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add stacktrace?

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? Following the 5.5 syntax you don't need "values" in the query: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

'Values' is a reserved word, so preferably change it or use back ticks to make sure it's dealt with as a column name...

```
String qry = "Create table Table1(`values` integer(2) primary key)";
```

Comment: That's not an issue here. I made it back, Thanks for your valuable feedback!